# Can radar detect electrical fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, radio, imaging, radar

Can we create a radar image of electrical fields, or this is even possible?
Do we need a detector opposite the emitter or does reflection work?
(see figure.1)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Electromagnetic waves do not interact with each other, so in general, e.g. in a vacuum, this cannot be done (no detection without interaction).

Under specific cirumstances you might be able to exploit potential nonlinear electrical properties of the medium the waves propagate in to indirectly detect such fields, but I am not aware of any practical implementations of this. Such a method would also have a very different working principle to ordinary radar.

Comment: May want to note that classically electromagnetic fields obey the superposition property and therefore don't directly interact but there are higher order quantum effects that [violate this assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics), however the entry levels of those effects are well beyond anything that would be expected in a radar.  This would be for two electromagnetic waves, this may not even apply to a EM wave and a static field as is requested in the question.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome The Wikipedia article you linked says for photons below 20 TeV, these interactions can be neglected even at intergalactic distances. The center-of-mass collisions at LHC top out at around 14 TeV. I think it's safe to leave out such exotic phenomena in an answer about detecting electromagnetic fields with radar; sometimes unneccesary details contribute to confusion rather than understanding.

Comment: I agree, I upvoted the answer as it exists

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by reflection. Maybe in nearfiled by measurening changes in electric filed valuse of reflected EM wave it's possible. So for this issue you need VNA instead of time domain radar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/386487)